# Force xml serialization on empty class attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I have a nested class:

```
public class guy{
    public address address {get; set;}
    public int age {get; set;}
}

public class address{
    public string name {get; set;}
}
```

Is there a way to serialize a `guy` object with no address name and get the following result with `XmlSerializer`?

```
<guy>
   <address>
       <name></name>
   </address>
   <age>10</age>
</guy>
```

Tired adding `[XmlElement(IsNullable = false)]` on `name` field but it doesn't seems to work

Comment: you named the property `addres` instead of `address`

Comment: @Innat3 Wrong copy paste, it was fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
public class guy
{
    [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
    public address address {get; set;}
    public int age {get; set;}
}
```

[XmlElementAttribute.IsNullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.isnullable?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_Serialization_XmlElementAttribute_IsNullable)

Otherwise make sure to initialize the field when you instantiate the class

```
public class guy
{
    public address address { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }

    public guy()
    {
        address = new address();
    }
}
```